# GetX Unbind Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-getx

I am using the `bindStream()` function with the `GetX` package inside a controller.

```
class FrediUserController extends GetxController {    
@override
void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    final userController = Get.find<FrediUserController>();
    var groupIds = userController.user.groups;
    groupList.bindStream(DatabaseManager().groupsStream(groupIds));
    ever(groupList, everCallback);
 }
}
```

But, when the groupIds update in the `FrediUserController` (with an ever function that gets triggered, I want to RE-bind the streams. Meaning, delete the existing ones and bind again with new ids, or replace the ones that have changed.

***Temporary Solution***: Inside `ever()` function

```
Get.delete<FrediGroupController>();
Get.put(FrediGroupController());
```

This code gets run everytime my `groupIds` change from the database. But I **do not** want to initiate my controllers every time a small thing changes, it is bad UX.

This seems difficult, could someone guide me to the right direction? Maybe there is a completely different approach to connecting two GetX controllers?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: the first one include editing the source code of the Getx package.**

first:
looking in the source code of the package :

```
  void bindStream(Stream<T> stream) {
     final listSubscriptions =
    _subscriptions[subject] ??= <StreamSubscription>[];
    listSubscriptions.add(stream.listen((va) => value = va));
  }
```

here is what the bind stream actually do, so if we want to access the `listSubscriptions` list, I would do:

```
 final listSubscriptions;
void bindStream(Stream<T> stream) {
     listSubscriptions =
    _subscriptions[subject] ??= <StreamSubscription>[];
    listSubscriptions.add(stream.listen((va) => value = va));
  }
```

now from your controller you will be able to cancel the `streamSubscription` stored in that list with the `cancel` method like this :

```
listSubscriptions[hereIndexOfThatSubscription].cancel();
```

then you can re-register it again with another `bindStream` call

second :
I believe also I've seen a method called `close()` for the `Rx<T>` that close the subscriptions put on it, but I don't know if it will help or not

```
Rx<String> text = ''.obs;
text.close();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Method 2 doesn't work. And I do not want to change the package source code. There HAS to be a way to reset the bindStream() function or to change streams coming from firebase without changing Getx Package.

Comment: Looking at the package source code right now regarding method 2 and this logically should work because it is iterating over the _subscriptions and cancelling them. Don't forget to bind the stream again. I would pull the bindstream in a separate function and calling it each time you want to rebind. In that function, close the rx variable before binding it. Call it each time you want to rebind. The object's stream itself also gets closed though, so you might want to reinitiating like this: rx.subject = GetStream<T>().

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this issue, and there appears to be no exposed close function. There is a different way to do it though, using rxdart:

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart' hide Rx;

class YourController extends GetxController {
  final value = 0.obs;
  final _closed = false.obs;
  
  void bindValue(Stream<int> valueStream) {
    _closed
      ..value = true
      ..value = false;

    final hasClosed = _closed.stream.where((c) => c).take(1);
    value.bindStream(
      valueStream.takeUntil(hasClosed)
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever you want to unbind, just set `_closed.value = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your Stream with where() (from the dart:async package):
Somewhere in your controller place

```
bool streamPaused = false;
```

which you set to true whenever you do not want the stream to change the value of your Rx, and then

```
myRx.bindStream(stream.where((_) => !streamPaused));
```

i.e. don't transform the stream depending on the events, but on the external parameter that lets you pause it.
No need for editing the getx source or using rxdart. Make sure, if needed, to update the value of the Rx when you set `streamPaused` from `true` back to `false` (here it helps if the stream is a `BehaviourSubject` from rxdart, but of course there are other options).