# GridView.count RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I know this question have been asked by many, its related to index of list to be viewd in grid view. The issue of mine is combining `GridView.count()` with `Obx()` using `Getx` and mapping through the resault which is `RxList<Product>` bindstream with query result.

here is my code:

```
Obx(() {
  return GridView.count(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    primary: false,
    crossAxisCount:
        controller.filteredProducts.isEmpty ? 1 : 4,
    childAspectRatio: (1.9 / 1),
    children: controller.filteredProducts.isEmpty
        ? const [
            Center(
              child: Text(
                  "No Products! Try starting to type name of Product"),
            ),
          ]
        : controller.filteredProducts
            .map(
              (p) => _item(
                title: p.name,
                price: p.getPrice().toString(),
                item: p.stockCount().toString(),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
  );
}),
```

in the above code there is no space to control index of list to solve the the error

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

in the background, I'm trying to update list of products upon searchfield instantly by starting to type the name. When I print the list of `filteredProducts` it shows the right results but in the view it shows this error when I start typing the product name.

Comment: May be it's happen because you update your list in the background.

Comment: well, any advice ?

Comment: Yeah you can trying to send a message via the IsolateNameServer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in you background task:

```
final sendPort =
        IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("notificationUpdatePort");
if (sendPort != null) {
  // The port might be null if the main isolate is not running.
  sendPort.send(['any', 'data', 'you', 'want']);
}
```

And to update your list, you can do like that:

```
var port = ReceivePort();
IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      port.sendPort, "notificationUpdatePort");
port.listen((dynamic data) async {
 // Here to update your list
});
```

Comment: this would help, but is there a way to do this using `GetX`? I think this question is somehow related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848756/getx-unbind-stream

Comment: I don't know how to use it using GetX